# Can't install Tableau due to "internal licensing error"

Tags: tableau-desktop

[image]

I have a Macbook Pro version(MacOS Monterey Version 12.0.1) I've been able to install Tableau, but when I try to open the application, I get the following error:

"The product is unable to start due to an internal licensing error. Please uninstall the product and try again"

I've tried completely removing Tableau from my computer and reinstalling, but haven't had any luck. I had this same issue several weeks ago--but I was able to download an older version of Tableau, and then upgrade to the latest version once I got it up and running. I've tried repeating the same process this time--but the older versions I've tried won't install on my mac, since they are outdated and considered a security threat.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!